# Актуальный log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Какая версия log4j актуальна? Как я понял, сейчас две основные 1.2 и 2.1.

Версия 1.2 поддерживается в связки с slf4j (для версии 2.1 не нашёл связку), и к тому же много статей написано именно про версию 1.2 (не таких уже и старых, надо сказать).  Никто не жалуется на 1.2. Но в версии 2.1, как я понял, отсутствует обратная совместимость (или усложнена). Как быть? Что учить?

Comment: log4j не актуален, учите logback )

Comment: Сильно ли отличается использование logback в соло режиме и logback+slf4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logback` как раз реализует `slf4j api` напрямую, поэтому ничем не отличается.

Для других логгеров есть адаптеры.